# Craps game - scanf automatically input huge number

Tags: c, variables, input, scanf, largenumber

The instructions for the part of the project I am having trouble with are:

"Playing" the game:
A second function playing() will be used to play a single game of craps until the player either wins or loses a bet, based upon the rules given above.  This function should be modify the current $ amount of the player's bank roll according to the game result, modify the array values of the player won or lost, and whether the player bet for or against him/herself.  Within the function, the player is asked whether s/he would like to place a bet. If so, the player must choose whether to bet "for" or "against" him/herself (see game rules above).  The player then "rolls the dice" (simulated by a call to the dice-rolling function rolling()).  This should be done interactively (via a key press from the player), rather than simply having the program continuously roll the dice until the game is over. After each roll, this function should report the two random dice values and the sum of the two. If, after the first roll, the game is not over, the player should be asked whether s/he would like to double the amount of the bet. When a roll causes the end of a game, the player is notified whether s/he won or lost money in that game overall, and the amount won or lost.  In all other cases, the player is notified that s/he needs to roll again.

**I have to code in a craps game that asks user for a bet amount and then they play craps. They have an initial bank roll of $100. I have to scan a bet amount in using scanf but it keeps making my bet amount very large without any user input. Can someone please help me, I have this project due tonight.**

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       


//function prototype
int rolling(void);
int playing(int c_amt);//inital money $100, min bet of $5, no max except money     you have
void beginning(void);
void ending(void);

int
main()
{
printf("\nWelcome to Craps! Get ready to play!");
int bank_amt = 100;
char y_n = 'n';

do
{
  bank_amt = playing(bank_amt);

  if(bank_amt == 0)
    {
       printf("\nYou bet and lost all your money! You can't play anymore.  Goodbye!");
       exit(0);
    }
  if(bank_amt != 0)
    {
      printf("\nYour current balance is %d %d", &bank_amt, bank_amt);
      printf("\nDo you want to play again? (y/n): ");
      scanf("\n%c", &y_n);
    }
 }
 while(y_n != 'n' && y_n != 'N');

 }


int
rolling(void)
{
  int dice1, dice2;
  char roll;
  srand((int)(time(NULL))); // "Seed" random number gen. with system time

  printf("\nPress enter to roll the dice!");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%c",&roll);
  dice1 = 1+rand()%6; // random num from 1-6
  dice2 = 1+rand()%6; // random num from 1-6

  return dice1+dice2;
}


  int
  playing(int c_amt)
  {
    char gametype, y_n = 'n';
    int total, point, for_u, against_u, winlose, win = 0, lose = 0;
    int moneychange, bet_amt, final_amt;

    printf("\nPlease press 'f' if you are betting for yourself and 'a' if your are betting against yourself.\n");
    scanf("\n%c", &gametype);

  do
   {
     printf("\nYour current bank balance is %d.", c_amt);
     printf("\nEnter the amount you want to bet: ");
     scanf(" %d", &bet_amt);
     printf("Bet amount: %d", bet_amt);

     if(bet_amt > c_amt || bet_amt < 5)
   {
        printf("\nYou dont have that much money or you placed a bet less than the minimum. Please place a proper bet.");
   }

   }
  while(bet_amt > c_amt);

    if (gametype == 'f' || gametype == 'F')
    {
      for_u++;
      printf("\nYou are betting for yourself!\nLets get started!");
      total = rolling();
      printf("\nThe value rolled is %d.", total);
      if (total == 7 || total == 11)
      {
        printf("\nGood job! You win :)");
        winlose = 1;
      }
      else if (total == 2 || total == 3 || total == 12)
      {
        printf("\nCraps, you lose.");
        winlose = 0;
      }
    else
    {
      point = total;
      printf("\nYour point is %d.", point);
      if(bet_amt*2 <= c_amt)
        {
          printf("\nWould you like to double your bet? (y/n)");
          scanf("\n%c", &y_n);
        }
          if(y_n == 'y' || y_n == 'Y')
          {
            bet_amt = bet_amt*2;
          }

      do
      {
          total = rolling();
          if(total == point)
            {
              printf("\nGood job! You win! :)");
              winlose = 1;
              break;
            }

      }
      while(total != 7);

     if(total == 7)
      {
      printf("You rolled a seven. You lose! :(");
      winlose = 0;
      }
    }
   }

  else if (gametype == 'a' || gametype == 'A')
   {
    against_u++;
    printf("You are betting against yourself!\nLet\'s get started!");
    total = rolling();
    printf("\nThe value rolled is %d.", total);
    if (total == 2 || total == 3 || total == 12
        {
        printf("Good job! You win :)\n");
        }
    else if (total == 7 || total == 11)
        {
        printf("Craps, you lose.\n");
        }
    else
        {
        point = total;
        printf("Your point is %d.\n", point);
        if(bet_amt*2 <= c_amt)
         {
         printf("\nWould you like to double your bet? (y/n)");
         scanf("\n%c", &y_n);
         }
        if(y_n == 'y' || y_n == 'Y')
         { 
         bet_amt = bet_amt*2;
         }

         do
         {
         total = rolling();
         if(total == 7)
           {
           printf("\nGood job! You win! :)");
           winlose=1;
           break;
           }

         }
         while(total != point);

         if(total == 7)
          {
          printf("You rolled a seven before making your point. You lose! :(");
          winlose = 0;
          }

          }
      }
          if(winlose ==  1)
            {
              final_amt = bet_amt + c_amt;
              win++;
            }
          else
            {
              final_amt = c_amt - bet_amt;
              lose++;
            }
        printf("Final amount is %d.", final_amt);
        return final_amt;
    }
```

Here is sample output:

```
Welcome to Craps! Get ready to play!
Please press 'f' if you are betting for yourself and 'a' if your are betting against yourself.

Your current bank balance is 100.
Enter the amount you want to bet: Bet amount: -1219958512
You dont have that much money or you placed a bet less than the minimum. Please place a proper bet.Final amount is 1219958612.
Your current balance is -1074871812 1219958612
Do you want to play again? (y/n):
```

Comment: Please fix up your code indentation and general formatting so that it is readable. Not just for our sake but for your own. Here are some errors which should get you past your current problem. But there are plenty more problems. 1. typo: `scanf("/n%c", &gametype);` should be `scanf("\n%c", &gametype);` 2. Missing a `while` before `(y_n != 'n' && y_n != 'N');` (not sure how you even got that to compile).

Comment: You are right, I apologize. This is my first time using Stack Overflow and so my format changed accidentally. I'm going through and fixing it.

Comment: Do you know what could be going wrong @kaylum ?

Comment: Did you fix those two things up that were pointed out? And if so, what was the behaviour of the program after that?

Comment: Yes, I fixed them! In order to see what the bet amount in coming out to be, I printed it out.Your current bank balance is 100.
Enter the amount you want to bet: 
Bet amount: -1220093680
You dont have that much money or you placed a bet less than the minimum. Please place a proper bet.
You current bank roll is: 1220093780

Answer (score -1):

Your formatting needs a lot of fixing to understand. However, the real issue is a buffer overflow, caused by not allocating enough memory to the `char`. Instead, I would suggest using simple `int` values like 0 and 1 to determine the player's choices.

Comment: I compiled the reformatted code and I am still getting a really large number for the bet amount.Your current bank balance is 100.
Enter the amount you want to bet:
Bet amount: -1220069104
You dont have that much money or you placed a bet less than the minimum. Please place a proper bet.Final amount is 1220069204.
Your current balance is -1075269652 1220069204

Comment: any ideas on what it could be @StardustGogeta

Comment: Ok will do! Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I recoded everything and it works now. I think you were right about the buffer overflow. Thank you so much for your help!